# Dynamically adding/removing sections within dynamically added sections

Tags: javascript

The script is supposed to have buttons to add or delete a section. Within that section there are buttons to add or delete a sub-section called 'row'. The problem I'm having is linking the row buttons to the section they were created in. Ie, no matter which section they belong to, they add or delete in the last section created. So I tried adding the `sec` argument to `mod_row()` but it seems it's always whatever the current value of `s` is, not the value of `s` when the button was created.

```
foo = document.createElement('p');
    var bar = document.createElement('button');
    bar.setAttribute('type','button');
    bar.onclick = function () { mod_row('add',s) };
    bar.appendChild(document.createTextNode('add row'));
foo.appendChild(bar);
    bar = document.createElement('button');
    bar.setAttribute('type','button');
    bar.onclick = function () { mod_row('del',s) };
    bar.appendChild(document.createTextNode('del row'));
foo.appendChild(bar);
section.appendChild(foo);

foo = document.createElement('div');
foo.setAttribute('id','magic_rows_'+s);
section.appendChild(foo);

function mod_row (mod,sec) {
    var row = "blah blah blah";
    var magic_rows = document.getElementById('magic_rows_'+sec);
    if (mod == 'add') {
        var new_p = document.createElement('p');
        new_p.setAttribute('id','row'+r);
        new_p.innerHTML = row;
        magic_rows.appendChild(new_p);
        r++;
    }
    else if (mod == 'del') {
        magic_rows.removeChild(magic_rows.lastChild);
        r--;
    }
}
```

Comment: This would be much easier if you used http://jquery.org/ or http://mootools.net/

Comment: yeah, my first thought was `$().live('click')`. it just makes it too easy!

Comment: This is my first javascript project, teaching myself. I was hoping not to need a huge library.. but maybe I'll have to look closer at one of those.

Comment: Doing your first project in raw JavaScript is a good idea, that will teach you some fundamentals. Then, you'll have a better grounding when you move on to using one of the usual toolkits; besides, you can't use the toolkits if you don't know JavaScript already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a classic closure problem in these two places:

```
bar.onclick = function () { mod_row('add', s) };
//...
bar.onclick = function () { mod_row('del', s) };
```

The problem is that the `s` inside those two functions refers to the `s` in the outside scope so when the click handlers are called, they'll end up using whatever value `s` had when the outer scope was finished. You need to force that `s` to be evaluated when you generate your click handler functions. The usual approach is to use a function to generate your callback functions:

```
bar.onclick = (function(inner_s) {
    return function() {
        mod_row('add', inner_s);
    }
})(s);
//...
bar.onclick = (function(inner_s) {
    return function() {
        mod_row('del', inner_s);
    }
})(s);
```

That extra layer of function evaluation forces `s` to be evaluated (as `inner_s`) when you assign to `bar.onclick` rather than when `bar.onclick` gets called.

You can't get away from dealing with pointers even in languages that claim not to have them.

**UPDATE**: Here's a clarification of how the funky self-executing functions work. This:

```
bar.onclick = (function(inner_s) {
    return function() {
        mod_row('add', inner_s);
    }
})(s);
```

is functionally equivalent to this:

```
function closure_hack(inner_s) {
    return function() {
        mod_row('add', inner_s);
    }   
}
bar.onclick = closure_hack(s);
```

When `closure_hack` is called, it is given `s` and `s` is a reference to a certain object. Then, inside `closure_hack`, `inner_s` refers to the same object that `s` refers to. Outside of `closure_hack`, `s` can change to **refer to a different object** but the `inner_s` still refers to the old one. The function call — either through `closure_hack` or the idiomatic self-executing function — is just a way to divorce the variable name, `s`, from the object it refers to: the goal is to grab a hold of what `s` refers to so that `s` can change without undesirable side effects.

This is tricky stuff and takes some getting used to. Closures trip everyone up, don't feel bad about being a bit confused.

Comment: I'm using this solution, it works great..but I don't understand how it gets `s` evaluated like I want. Having trouble understanding callback functions and anonymous functions in general. Working through it though. In particular, how does `bar.onclick = (...)(s);` work? Obviously it somehow passes `s` to the functions inside, but what is that construction?

Comment: @djeikyb: I added an update to, hopefully, explain what's going on with the self-executing functions and why they're used.

Comment: Ah, that helps, especially seeing the long form. And [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anonymous_function#JavaScript) explains that the () executes the preceding anon function. Also found an [msdn article on closures](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2003/09/17/53028.aspx) which helps, in conjunction with your explanation.

Comment: @djeikyb: Sometimes the `(function() { /*...*/ })();` construct is used to make a private scope too, you'll see that version of it in a lot of jQuery plugins. These techniques are standard (and necessary) in functional programming as well.